# Existence of unique measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous, bounded, non-decreasing and such that $\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x) = 0$.

Can anybody show me why there exists a unique (!) measure $m_F$ on $(\mathbb R, B(\mathbb R))$ such that $m_F((- \infty, x]) = F(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$?

(Where $B(\mathbb R)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb R$ induced by the Euclidean topology.)

Comment: Every monotone function is differentiable everywhere except for a subset of Lebesgue measure $0$. So simply take $m_F(A)=\int_A F'(x)dx$, right?

Comment: It doesn't seem that "continuous" or "bounded" conditions play a role here. Unless I'm wrong about the integral part.

Comment: Hmm I thought that I should construct a suitable outer measure m* and show that Borel sets are m*-measurable...not?

Comment: It may help to google the keyword *Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure*.

Comment: I googled it. It helped a lot, thank you!